# Jmeter multi-user execution

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, execution

I have a JMeter execution scenario. Here it goes:

1. Login with 1 credential.
2. Perform an operation.
3. Logout.

Now, issues:
I need to login using 1 credential and play the operation part with multiple concurrent users, even though I have just 1 login credential. How do I execute such a scenario ?

Please explain the whole procedure in detail as following an instructional overview sometimes leads to blockage in moving further.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go through  the following guide to setup the rest of the test

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial/

You need to use once only controller for login action. Ideally you want to use different users to avoid race conditions caused by using the same user.

Answer (score 0):

If your system allows multiple logins with the same credentials it should not be a problem, just a[dd as many users](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) as you need in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and each of the virtual users will execute these 3 requests upside down.

[image]

You can add [__threadNum() function](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) as the request label prefix or postfix in order to be able to distinguish virtual users and [`${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to track Thread Group loops/iterations.

[image]